# CSS Menu Layout in Sub-List Parent

Tags: html, css

I have been using my free time to improve my HTML knowledge during my holiday.

During the time I was designing a CSS Menu. I face some problem and don't know how to solve them.

I tried to search from Google. Because of my poor English, I was unable to find a solution, so I seek help here.

**Problem:**

I tried to design a CSS Menu with Expandable sub-menu.
Why doesn't the sub-menu's parent list change?

As you can see from the screenshot. The **Product** menu is different with others.

Is there any solution?

**ScreenShot**

Due to my reputation I can't provide a screenshot, so I'll provide a link:

http://i151.photobucket.com/albums/s155/HongJaiz/CSSMenu.jpg

**CSS3 Coding**

```
body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#fff));

}

.navbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

ul#expList {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
    background: url(shad2.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
}

li#expList {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
    background: url(shad2.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

ul#expList li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background: #cbcbcb url(border.png) no-repeat;
    color: #174867;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}

ul#expList li a:hover {
    background: #ebebeb url(border.png) no-repeat;
    color: #67a5cd;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 30px;
}
```

**HTML Coding**

```
<ul id="expList">
    <li class="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="freebies">Product
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">List 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a href="">Register</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I re-tagged your question with CSS and CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just coz you have given style to `<a></a>` of `<li></li>` and in case of parent of submenu i.e **`Product`** you haven't wrapped it in `<a></a>` tag, doing so will solve your problem

```
<ul id="expList">
    <li class="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="freebies"><a>Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">List 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a href="">Register</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Uttara.
You solved my problem.

But after I add in the <a> inside the Product.
The List 1,List 2 and List 3 unable expand to show out.